# Apex (hidden) - How to access the code?

Tags: apex, batch

I' like to access the code of an APEX Batch, but it's hidden ...
I've already had this issue for a managed package, but this time I don't know where to look !
Any idea ?

[image]

Edit :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you accidentally opened the wrong class (i.e. the one that's in a managed package). The API is a bit stricter than the UI, so you might want to just go to Setup > Develop > Apex Classes, where you can view the code for any of your local classes, plus any of the code for any global class in a managed package.

Comment: Thanks, so I tryied openning the Apex Code by using the Setup menu, the fact code is in a managed Package as excpected but the class isn't Global. I've to ask the team that developped the package ; any idea why that team build a managed package ? Because it is build only for our organization, doesn't it costs to make the package public, downloadable on the AppExchange ?
Edit : I edited my question with a screenshot

Comment: @AlexisMASSON Could be that they wanted it to be upgradeable, or perhaps to lock down the code. There's no way to know without asking them. Public apps can cost money, but only if it is not free, and private managed apps are also possible (and free).